# Cancel Button in Inputbox doesn't close

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am using an inputbox on a click of a button  to store a value and perform some validations on the same. My problem is on click of cancel button it doesn't close and instead popups out information for a null check. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

For a null check it pops out "please enter a value and try again".
The problem is even if i click on cancel it shows the same message like "please enter a value and try again" and when i dont provide any value and click on ok it shows the same message "please enter a value and try again"

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var inputValue:string;
begin
  repeat
    inputValue:=InputBox('Enter a value', 'value','');
    if (inputValue<>'') then
    begin
      if MessageDlg('Do You want to enter this value ' +inputValue+'?',mtInformation,[mbYes,mbNo],0)= mrYes then
        MessageDlg('Your Value got stored', mtInformation,[mbOk],0)
    end;
  until(inputValue='');

  repeat
    if (inputValue = '') then
      MessageDlg('Please Enter a value and try again', mtInformation,[mbOk],0) ;
    inputValue:=InputBox('Enter a value', 'value','');
    if (inputValue<>'') then
    begin
      if MessageDlg('Do You want to enter this value ' +inputValue+'?',mtInformation,[mbYes,mbNo],0)= mrYes then
        MessageDlg('Your Value got stored', mtInformation,[mbOk],0)
    end;
  until (inputValue<>'') ;
end;
```

Comment: I made a small edit to format the code a little, but it's still close to unreadable. Please could you address this with an edit. Please also make it clear what "popups out information for a null check" means.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Please can you also format the code in a readable way. And do we really need to see all of it? Isn't it enough to show just a single of the repeat blocks? Please spend a bit more time crafting questions.

Comment: In order to avoid entering values for the rest of your days, you may consider to use the [Break procedure](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Break) to exit the `repeat` loop when some of your condition is met

Comment: The [MessageDlg](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.MessageDlg) returns mrOk when the ok button is pressed and mrCancel when the cancel button is pressed. Is this the information you are looking for?

Comment: MessageDlg works fine but the problem is with InputBox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your parameter `default` for function [InputBox](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=InputBox) is empty string. Empty string also is value that function returned when user is pressed "Cancel" button.

> If the user presses OK, the default or user entered data is stored in
>   the return string, otherwise an empty string is returned.

In this case you can not determine where it came from this value(From Ok or from Cancel).

I recommend to use [InputQuery](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=InputQuery) instead InputBox.

Something like :

```
var
  InputValue : string;
  CustIsPressOK : boolean;
begin

  repeat
    CustIsPressOK := InputQuery('Enter a value', 'value',InputValue);

    if CustIsPressOK then
      begin
        if InputValue <> '' then
          begin
            if MessageDlg('Do You want to enter this value ' +inputValue+'?',mtInformation,[mbYes,mbNo],0)= mrYes then
              MessageDlg('Your Value got stored', mtInformation,[mbOk],0);
          end
        else
          begin
            //user is pressed OK button but value is empty string
            MessageDlg('Please Enter a value and try again', mtInformation,[mbOk],0) ;
          end;
      end;
    until (CustIsPressOK = false) or (CustIsPressOK and (InputValue <> ''));
```